# Unable to locate the Ubuntu 16.04.04 kernel version 4.15.0-46 ISO to install on Dell R740 server

Tags: system-installation, kernel, dell

I am trying to install Ubuntu 16.04.01 and .04 on Dell R740 server but not able to complete the installation due to no partitions being detected.

Dell officially confirmed that only **Ubuntu 16.04.04 kernel version 4.15.0-46** will be supported to install.

How can I complete the installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install 16.04.5, or 18.04.

16.04.5 can be found [here](http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04.5/)

Comment: Thank you. I have installed 18.04.1 version 4.15.0-29

Comment: It is working on Dell R740 (PERC H740P) RAID controller.

Comment: 18.04 has the same kernel.